# "What does she look like?" vs. "How does she look like?"

Tags: meaning

I have heard "What does she look like" said a lot and sometimes "How does she look like?".
Is there any difference between them, if yes What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get your answer from here:
http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2059535.
These are very different questions. Let me show you in pairs.

What does she look like? = describe her physical appearance, generally.
How does she look? = describe her physical appearance, right now. For example, "She looks beautiful today, with her hair done up."

Disclaimer-:(answer adopted from source)

Answer (score 5):

Just based on native instinct, both questions mean roughly the same thing, but ...

> "What does she look like?"

Since it's a "what" question, I think this phrasing *suggests* that the answer should be a noun:

- she looks **like** a cat
- she looks **like** an 80's pop star

etc.

> "How does she look?"

(*Note the question sounds more natural without "like".*)

Since it's a "how" question, I think this question fits better if the expected answer is a descriptive adjective:

- she looks great
- she looks terrible

etc.

But they are somewhat interchangeable. The second form of the question is more common. The first form of the question registers some surprise, suggesting that someone looks a bit strange.

Comment: If we took the question "What does she look like?" literally, yes, the answer should be some object or class that she resembles. But in practice, this is an idiom, and the answer is often, "She's very pretty" or "She looks tired", or any description of her appearance.

Answer (score 5):

"What" is pointing to an objective description (colors, kind of clothes etc.).

"How" is pointing to an subjective description that involves perception, opinion (*pretty, beautiful* etc.).

Answer (score 2):

*How does she look like?* sounds like a direct translation from the German *Wie sieht sie aus?* because *wie* means *how* in English.  I hear Germans make this mistake all the time.

So, the translation is logical, but we ask the question with *what* in English.

Comment: I work in academia and hear speakers of many different languages saying ''How does she look like?'' when they speak English, not sure what the origin is.